# Python timer with threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, timer

I wanted to create a simple timer script to use it with my telegram bot, but something doesn't work like I want it to. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from threading import Timer


class Timer:
  def __init__(self, router):
    self.routes = [
            ("^/timer\s(?P<time>[^$]+)$", self.main),
            ]

  def timer_end(self):
    print 'Timer End'

  def main(self, message, match):
     Timer(5, self.timer_end, ()).start()
```

I always get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)
```

It would be great if someone could help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You import Timer, then you create a class which overwrites Timer.  Maybe you should just "import threading" then use "threading.Timer" to distinguish the two?

Comment: Oops, I could have noticed that myself. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As @swstephe mentioned in a comment:

> You import Timer, then you create a class which overwrites Timer. Maybe you should just "import threading" then use "threading.Timer" to distinguish the two?